# How can I load different jsp page on clicking the tab in extjs 4?

Tags: java, javascript, extjs

```
I have created 3 tabs in my home.jsp.
```

what I want is on clicking the tab it loads another jsp(it have script also). i have used

```
   title: 'Home'  
            autoLoad: {
                url: 'UserProfile', 
                script:true
            }
        }
```

this code. But it lods only simple text. the script part is not loaded. how can I load script properly?

Comment: @IJP I have already doing the same thing but only jsp plain content is added. script part is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
tabObj.update(responseText)

responseText: call a ajax call to "UserProfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 title: 'Home'  
            autoLoad: {
                url: 'UserProfile.jsp', 
                scripts:true
            }
        }
```

Its "scripts" and not as "script"

Comment: Still Only simple text I am getting not script.

Comment: after changing "script" to "scripts" I am getting the same old data means script part I am not getting.